# given $p,q,r \ge 3$ study the diophantine equation $x^py^q=z^r-1$ using the $abc$-conjecture

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, diophantine-equations, radicals, abc-conjecture

I want to show that given $p,q,r \ge 3$ the diophantine equation $x^py^q=z^r-1$ has only finitely many solutions with $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N} = 1 ,2, \dots$ assuming the $abc$-conjecture.

The proof supposedly goes in two steps:

1. $\text{rad}(x^p y^q z^r) < z^{\frac{2r}{3}}$
2. Now apply the $abc$-conjecture to conclude that there are only finitely many solutions.

The statement of the $abc$-conjecture that we use is:

For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists only finitely many $ABC$-triples $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{N}^3$ s.t. $$c > (\text{rad}(abc))^{1+\epsilon}.$$

For step 1, I made some observations:

- $\text{rad}(x^py^qz^r) = \text{rad}(xyz) \le xyz \le (z^r-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}z$
- $\text{rad}(x^py^qz^r) = \text{rad}{(z^r-1)z}$

Any help is appreciated; I'm mainly stuck at the first part.

EDIT:

For step 1 we use the further observations $(z^r-1) < z^r$, and $z \le z^{\frac{r}{3}}$, to find that $\text{rad}(x^py^qz^r) = \text{rad}(xyz) \le xyz \le (z^r-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}z < z^{\frac{2r}{3}}$.

EDIT:
For step 2 take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, then the $abc$-conjecture states that there are only finite solutions with $z^r > \text{rad}(x^py^qz^r)^{1 + \epsilon} = \text{rad}(x^py^qz^r)^{1 + \frac{1}{2}} = \text{rad}(x^py^qz^r)^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

But from step 1 we have $z^{\frac{2r}{3}} > \text{rad}(x^py^qz^r)$ which implies $z^r > \text{rad}(x^py^qz^r)^{\frac{3}{2}}$, allowing us to conclude that we have only finitely many solutions.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Hint for first part: $z^r-1<z^r,z\leq z^{r/3}$.

Comment: Do you mean: $\text{rad}(x^py^qz^r) = \text{rad}{(z^r-1)z} \le (z^r-1)z \le z^r z^{\frac{r}{3}}=z^{\frac{4r}{3}}$, because that would not work.

Comment: In your first observation you have $(z^r-1)^{1/3}$, use that.